# Index out of range on plt.title

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to prepare a program to be provided in the arguments a file with a json format that reads parameters to fill a plot. I'm using matplotlib.

If I put in the code `plt.title("Test title")` everything goes well

If I put

`{ "title": "Test title" }` in the file and set the path in the program (not in the argument), replacing the previous to `plt.title(json_file["title"])` everything goes well.

But if I put in the arguments call a `-f path/to/json`, even though the json file loads correctly, when the line `plt.title(json_file["title"])` is called raises index out of range error. I don't get why, because I'm not going through any array.

I've searched in stackoverflow and tried in the documentation of title, but it doesn't report that it can raise this error.

One thing I'm doing is reading the json file with yaml, because with json I received everything in unicode and was having the same error so I tried something different.

The following code is a little bit simpler, but reproduces the error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
import yaml
import sys

def configure(json_file):
    title = json_file["title"]
    plt.title(title)

def handleArguments():
    arguments = sys.argv
    # The first item is removed because it's the filename
    arguments.pop(0)
    file = None
    while(len(arguments) > 0):
        argument = arguments[0]
        if(argument == "-f"):
            file = arguments[1]
            arguments.pop(0)
            arguments.pop(0)
        else:
            raise Exception('Argument not found: {}'.format(argument))
    return (file)

(file) = handleArguments()
# file = "data_feed/test.json"
f = open(file,)
# Reading with yaml because json.load reads as unicode, not strings
json_file = yaml.safe_load(f)

configure(json_file)

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 5, 8]

plt.plot(x, y)  
plt.show()
```

Here is a Traceback as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete_me.py", line 31, in <module>
    configure(json_file)
  File "delete_me.py", line 8, in configure
    plt.title(title)
  File "/home/silkking/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1419, in title
    return gca().set_title(s, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/silkking/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 969, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/home/silkking/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 586, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/home/silkking/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 533, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/silkking/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 161, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/home/silkking/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1046, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1823, in __init__
    baseName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine. Paste the traceback as well.

Comment: I've just added the traceback. Could it be that is running some code in cache?

Comment: Um... Can you run the script as python3? I ran your script as `python3 file.py -f file.json`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the problem was I was running it with python2. With python 3 runs perfectly.

Comment: Just note that python 2 has been deprecated for a while and should not be used when possible.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I don't understand, running it with python2 gives and error, but with python3 it's ok.